# Wireless mouse fails, wired mouse works

Tags: drivers, wireless, mouse

I am a problem with my USB wireless mice. They have always been flaky but stopped working completely in the last two days. Same mice work fine on Windows 10 computer, so the problem is not the mice, batteries, etc.

Trackpad works, plugging wired mouse works, so it looks like it is the wireless connection that has failed.

Can I reset or reinstall the wireless part of the mouse driver? Is there a way to check the frequency it is operating on?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Ubuntu ? Did you need to install a driver in the first place to get the mouse working?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was the mouse, of course. Probably an hour after I posted it occurred to me that the wireless control was between the mouse and the USB dongle and not software dependent.